# How can I use googles "Interesting Calendars" with their v3 FreeBusy API?

Tags: google-calendar-api

When I attempt to use a calendar such as `en.usa#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com` (Or anything with the ID ending in `group.v.calendar.google.com`) The FreeBusy API errors with:

```
"calendars": {
  "en.usa#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com": {
   "errors": [
    {
     "domain": "global",
     "reason": "notFound"
    }
   ],
   "busy": []
  }
 }
```

Making the same request but asking for another calendar succeeds.

The request I am making is reproducible in the Google API Docs at https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/freebusy/query

Where the request body is:

```
{
  "timeMin": "2018-07-01T11:21:53.682-04:00",
  "timeMax": "2018-08-25T11:21:53.682-04:00",
  "items": [
    {
      "id": "en.usa#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com"
    }
  ],
  "timeZone": "UTC"
}
```

I ruled out credentials being an issue; the same credentials work with this calendarId when it is used on the events API. This should also mean that the `calendarId` is valid.

The google account being used has this interesting calendar added to it. (Those events show up in the combined view)

Comment: You may refer with this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15649046/google-calendar-freebusy-giving-error-notfound-with-one-account-but-not-anoth/15724390#15724390) which recommended to have the owner of the Apps for Business account add the developer email address (`#####@developer.gserviceaccount.com`) as a delegate. You may also go into the calendar sharing page and explicitly share your calendar with the `#####@developer.gserviceaccount.com` email address.